# SQL query for counts and accessing another tables

Tags: sql

I would like to do the following query:

count the # of people by specific attribute BUT ONLY IF they have done a particular action on my site.

to count the # of people by attribute:

`select attribute, count(*) from users  group by attribute`

now, the particular action is stored in table Y.

so I would like to perform the count only if this particular user has an entry in table Y. user would be stored by id. so basically what I'd like to do is;

`select attribute, count(*) from users group by attribute IF Y has user_id of user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar pointed out, we don't want multiple rows to occur if we use a simple join.
Therefore we make a temporary table to join with the distinct IDs.

```
select attribute, count(*) from users as u, 
(select distinct user_id from Y) as Y2
where U.user_id = Y2.user_id 
group by attribute;
```

Comment: This will give the wrong answer if the user has multiple entries in Y.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified accordingly by using a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT attribute, COUNT(*)
FROM USERS AS u
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
      FROM Y) AS y
ON u.user_id = y.user_id
GROUP BY attribute
```

or:

```
SELECT attribute, COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM y)
GROUP BY attribute
```

Comment: Exists is much faster than searching using IN.

Comment: That probably depends on the SQL implementation. I usually use the `JOIN` anyway, as it's usually faster in MySQL.

Comment: For few records using IN will be faster, But if large records then using Exists will be much better than IN